# Separate session for each directory in htdocs folder in apache

Tags: php, apache, session, xampp

I have hosted more than one projects on the same server i.e; for each project i have created a separate directory in htdocs folder. The problem is that the same session is shared between all of the projects. Is there any way we can separate the session for **each project directory**?

i am using the default PHP session interface

Note: All the projects shares some common variable names stored in session, like **isLoggedin**. So if a user is logged in any one of the projects then he can also access other projects without login (big issue).

One way to stop this is to use diiferent variable names for each project. So that they do not interfear ex: **isLoggedIn_Project1**, **isLoggedIn_Project2** etc. *

> But at this point we cannot change the source code for projects, that
>   would be a lot of effort. So kindly suggest a way through which the
>   apache server create/use different session for each project directory

Answer (score 1):

Use the [session_name](http://us.php.net/session_name) function to differentiate between the pages/sites.

Comment: how the following scenario could be handled. All the projects uses the session variable name isLoggedIn so if a user is logged-in in any one of the projects then he can also access other projects without login.